# Roman words to describe suicide

Tags: idiom, roman-law

The Romans did not have a single word to describe suicide; that is a modern (by our standards) invention. There was the expression *mors voluntāria*, volitional death. They also had verbal phrases, such as *manus* or *mors* plus verb, e.g. *manus sibī īnferre*, or *sibī mortem conscisere* and *sibī necem cōnscīscere*. These all reflect something along the lines of *to lay death* or *murder upon oneself*.

Catherine Ruff, in her [MA of 1974](https://scholarship.richmond.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1956&context=masters-theses), goes into details on the term *suicide*. She mentions that:

> There is some speculation that the term first appeared in 1671 in England, but Dr. Samuel Johnson deleted it from his dictionary.³ The Chronological English Dictionary says it appeared in 1651.⁴ Skeat added that the word:
>
> > seems to have been suggested by the queer words *suicist*, a selfish man, and *suicism*, selfishness, which had been coined at an earlier date, and were used by Whitlock in an essay entitled “The Grand Schismatic,” or “Suist Anatomical” in his zootamia.⁵
> > ―Ruff 1974: 8f.

With regards to Roman terms, she explains that:

> Without an inherited term for self-killing the Romans were able to create a concept giving it their own connotation.
> ―Ruff 1974: 9.

This is exemplified by her statistics on the usage of *ipse* as an intensifier (pp. 5f:

- *ipse:* especially pre-Catonian suicide

  - used by: Cicero, Tacitus
  - omitted by: Seneca
- Examples:

  - Cicero:

    - mortem sibī ipse cōnscīsset
    - sēsē ipsā morte multāvisset
    - magium sē ipsum interfēcisse
  - Tacitus:

    - sē ipse ferro trānsēgit
    - sē ipsum interfēcit
  - Seneca:

    - fīnem vītae suae manū suā imposuit
    - currere ad mortem effēcerī̆s
    - adpetere mortem
    - sē dēvōvit
    - illa ad nōs vēniat an ad illam nōs
  - Augustine (denouncing Lūcrētia)

    - sē ipsam occidit
    - sē ipsīs homicīdia committerent
    - ipsīs necem īnferāmus

**What I am looking for specifically, are phrases and phrasings used in Roman law to describe suicide.** I am particularly interested in anything up to and including Late Antiquity, not the Middle Ages (though this periodisation is of course quite fluent). Answers listing usage and references would be most helpful, as this would allow me to build a database of where phrases are found and how they were used.

(Answers that I use for my work, will of course be credited.)